# Compact image of adjoint action

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $H$ a connected Lie-subgroup.
Suppose that for every compact subset $K\subset G/H$ the $H$-orbit $H.K$ is relatively compact in $G/H$.

Is it true that the image of the adjoint representation ad$(H)\subset$GL$(\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h)$ is compact?
Here $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ are the Lie algebras of $G$ and $H$.